# OAuthInsufficientScope when trying to read Reddit posts

Tags: python, reddit, praw

I'm using [Oauth2Util](https://github.com/SmBe19/praw-OAuth2Util/tree/master/OAuth2Util) for authorization purposes. When the bot tries to read posts off of a subreddit, it says `praw.errors.OAuthInsufficientScope: insufficient_scope on url https://oauth.reddit.com/r/pics/new.json?limit=200`

Answer (score 0):

You need "history" scope for this to work.

Regenerate your token with this scope and try again.